# Read Standard Output and check status of multiple processes VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, process, stdout

I run multiple command line processes, starting them in a loop. It works and starts all of them async.

```
Public Sub DoWork
Dim i As Integer = 0
        While (Args_reader.Peek() > -1)
            i = i + 1
            MyArg = Args_reader.ReadLine
            Dim MyArg As String
            Dim MyProcess(i) As Process
            MyProcess(i) = New Process
            With MyProcess(i).StartInfo
                .FileName = MyFile
                .Arguments = MyArg
                .UseShellExecute = False
                .CreateNoWindow = True
                .RedirectStandardInput = True
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            End With
            MyProcess(i).Start()
        End While
        Args_reader.Close()
        i = 0
End Sub
```

Haw can I read stdOutput for all of them and check their status? 
I need to wait until they finish to continue executing the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to assign `async` events to `every process` inside a loop, so they get fired when that process has any output. Standard Output or Error Output:

```
 Dim Proceso As New Process

 'Add the event handlers:

 AddHandler Proceso.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf CallbackProcesoAsync
 AddHandler Proceso.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorDataReceivedAsync

 Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
 startInfo.FileName = execFile
 startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
 startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
 Proceso.StartInfo = startInfo
 Proceso.Start()
```

the async events should be something like this:

```
 Private Sub CallbackProcesoAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)

    If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then

       'args.Data have the output

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ErrorDataReceivedAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)

   If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then

       'args.Data have the output

   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Yep. Looks easy. I just don't understand, how can I receive the output from all processes, I started in a loop. And I don't know, how many processes it could be. All depends on the arguments lines, read from the text file. It may be whatever.
Do I have to make another loops in callback and errorreceive?

Comment: Because each process will trigger the async event. The argument sender as object is the Process that is invoking the event and you can have it's output with the args parameter.

Comment: Check this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes. It works. I can read all the outputs from all my processes. Thank you.

But. Another question, how can I determine which one is the process I need for some reason?

For example, how can I stop the process clicking a Button? Right now I cannot stop even all of them.

            MyProcess.Kill()
            MyProcess.Close()
            MyProcess.Dispose()

Doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes! Works now! Thank you again.