# How to interact with process output?

Tags: vb.net, shell, process, ffmpeg, output

Ok so at the moment I have a program which runs FFmpeg using a process in VB.net. I send the process arguments in the startinfo as well as other things like the file location. When I run the code it sends the console output to the debug console; this is probably because I have the .UseShellExecute = False and processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

My question is: How do I make something which can interpret the output? Also with FFmpeg, the process is continuous so the process is always running for the most part and constantly adding more output lines in the debug console.

The code I am using:

```
Dim process As New Process
        Dim processInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        processInfo.FileName = tempPath
        processInfo.Arguments = ("-r 1/.1 -i " + link + " -c copy " + saveLocation + "\" + streamerName + ".ts")
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        process.StartInfo = processInfo
        process.Start()
```

I tried this with no luck.

```
Dim output As String
        Using StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
            output = StreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString
        End Using
```

Edit: I now have this code:

```
Dim process As New Process
        AddHandler process.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf CallbackProcesoAsync
        AddHandler process.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorDataReceivedAsync
        Dim processInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        processInfo.FileName = tempPath
        processInfo.Arguments = ("-r 1/.1 -i " + link + " -c copy " + saveLocation + "\" + streamerName + ".ts")
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        process.StartInfo = processInfo
        process.Start()
        processes.Add(Tuple.Create(tempPath, streamerName))
        Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to record " + streamerName)
        Dim output As String
        Using StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
            output = StreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CallbackProcesoAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = args.Data
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ErrorDataReceivedAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = args.Data
    End If
End Sub
```

But I have not recieved any outputs to the richtextboxes?

I feel like it has something to do with the streamReader so I removed it and it still didn't work? I don't have any more ideas what it could be.

Comment: Doesn't your application crash on `output = StreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString` ?

Comment: It doesn't crash but if I do RichTextBox1.Text = output
it crashes and says like cross threading between threads- because I multithreading the main process like 5 times.

Comment: I can just invoke the output though and it all works, but I still want to get the running output in real time, because after I end the stream it displays the output of what just happened, so is there no way I can display this error output live?

Comment: Try replacing `RichTextBox2.Text = args.Data` with `RichTextBox2.Text &= args.Data & vbnewline` And same for richtextbox1.

Comment: This didn't work but I managed to put invoke(Sub()) richtextbox1.text = richtextbox1 + output) This works but only after the thread has ended it displays the message

Comment: Strange... maybe something is freezing your form and doesn't let your textboxes update. Try `Debug.WriteLine(args.Data)` and tell me if the output updates in real time in the output window

Comment: And also remove the code `Dim output As String
        Using StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
            output = StreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString
        End Using` it has no reason to exist and also may freeze your form (Unilikely).

Comment: I don't know anymore, to be honest, I removed the stuff you said and such, with still no luck. Is there a good place to learn about reading process inputs? Because I'm probably going to rewrite the whole code again due to it being pretty messy. And then I will see what I can do with that.

Comment: I use this code to capture the output of application and it works. I don't know what is happening. The last thing i can think may solve the problem is to change the code `processInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"` and `processInfo.Arguments = "/c """ & tempPath & """ -r 1/.1 -i " & link & " -c copy " & saveLocation & "\" & streamerName & ".ts"`

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg outputs all debug information to StdErr instead of StdOut. Use RedirectStandardError to true and try to read StandardError from the process.

Comment: Is there not a way to see this updating? I routed the standarderror to show up in a rich text box but I'm guessing text will only appear when an error occurs? Is there no way to show all of the process output text?

Comment: You can set a callback to be notified when new data is available. [See this VB example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19514271/6347620)